# Why have I to use my memory usb to be able to start ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: installation, 12.04

I used a memory usb to install ubuntu 12.04, since I removed " windows 7 ", now ubuntu it is my only operating system, but I had a problem when I stopped installing it, to be able to initiate ubuntu, I have to have connected the memory USB, if I her do not connect the only thing that goes out it is a screen of black color with a low script blinking, to insure myself that the problem was with the memory USB, I eliminated all his files that it had to install ubuntu, when I turned it to trying with the memory usb formatted, it continued starting and when it was removing it, only the screen was going out in black. How can I arrange it?

Another thing that I noticed is that it never goes out GRUB's menu

Answer (score 1):

I think it may have installed some part of the booting process to your usb-stick.  That's what happened to me.  In the forums they suggested the use of [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), which solved my problem.

I would advice you to give that a spin.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's something wrong with your BIOS.

Hold the Delete(or F2, or Alt) key while starting up, the you will see the BIOS.

Then change your boot priority to "Hard Drive" instead of "USB Stick"

Comment: Already it had modified the BIOS, when it had it in the normal options the screen was remaining in black with a low script blinking, then I made that first it was detecting the external devices, bony the memory USB and already it was starting ubuntu, but if I put the normal ones the screen remains in black.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Grub didn't install properly on my local drive--it installed itself on my flash drive!

Run the tool Boot Repair at it's default settings, and you should be good to go:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair